# NullpointerException in Listview on android

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone I'm working with a `ListView` and when i open the activity my app crashes due to a `NullPointerException`. Everything is declared, so I really have no idea of why this is happening.

So I have this layouts:

delete.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_deleteAll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/deleteAll"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my `ListActivity` class is:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import com.example.calendar.DBHandler;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DeleteAppointment extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

    DBHandler db;
    Appointment app;
    ListView list;
    Cursor cursor;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.delete);
        Button deleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteAll);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        deleteAll.setOnClickListener(this);
        db = new DBHandler(this);
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(db.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{app._date, app._title, app._time, app._details}, null, null, "asc");
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] columns = new String[]{app._date, app._title, app._time, app._details};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.date, R.id.name, R.id.time, R.id.details};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, columns, to);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){  
        case R.id.btn_deleteAll:
            finish();
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

The line where it crashes is line 28, which is

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(db.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{app._date, app._title, app._time, app._details}, null, null, "asc");
```

Logcat stacktrace:

```
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calendar/com.example.calendar.DeleteAppointment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.example.calendar.DeleteAppointment.onCreate(DeleteAppointment.java:28)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-23 18:54:51.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
```

Please help me.

Comment: `Everything is declared`  Declaring will reserve space and set the reference pointer to null.  What leads you to believe that declaring is sufficient?  Unless you also initialise the variable to an instance of the appropriate type, then trying to access it will cause a NullPointerException.  Where do you initialise `app` for example - and by looking at that line and your code, it seems that `app` must be null.

Comment: are you sure is getContentResolver() returning null? have you declared  btn_deleteAll inside R.layout.delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app` is not initialized in your code. you need initialize that before using

you need something like:

```
app =  new Appointment();
```

and if you are using a `ListActivity`, you need to have a `ListView` who's id is `android.R.list` in your `layout` file.

Comment: Awesome. By the way, just one more simple question. I have two classes handling the database events: Appointment and DBHandler. Appointment is a class with the methods to get the values and the DBHandler is the one with the methods with queries and all. Which one is the provider. Because now I have a different error saying that it wasn't possible to get provider

Comment: sorry i don't get your mean, but if you have another question you can ask new question that other programmer can help you,

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.R.id.list` or `getListView()` instead of `R.id.list` to initialize ListView :

```
 list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

OR

```
list = getListView();
```